# I did not know how to Express in terms of a and b

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The vectors  a  and  b  are the two vectors drawn from a vertex of a square to the two adjacent vertices. Express in terms of  a  and  b  the vector of the diagonal drawn from the same vertex.

Comment: Between this and [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3196151/draw-a-possible-graph-representing-the-acquaintances-in-this-group-of-five-peopl) it really looks like you are just posting your homework here for us to do for you.  Please edit your post to explain what you have tried and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: sorry lulu but it is not my homework it is a test to join an university and i did not study that in high school that s it

Comment: I suggest looking up [addition of vectors](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorAddition.html)....there are plenty of online resources for that sort of thing.

Comment: thank you so much and by the way Istudy in french so I have a lot of problems to know which cours is it

Comment: The fact that you study in French is by *NO* means an impediment! Some of the best mathematicians were (and still are!) French!